# Save and Restore state for view with custom attributes

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-custom-view

I have a custom view aiming to switch between two currencies. The idea is simple, a main text field with a currency abbreviation, a button to switch and a chip with the converted amount.

In the custom view, I have another custom view which contains an `EditText` and a `TextView` which is what I use for the main amount display. Here is a small diagram of the 'layout' of the views:

[image: Custom View layout]

As you can see, there isn't a huge amount going on here in terms of components. However, internally, I am doing a certain amount of calculations and logic.

In the `AmountEditText` view, I have a single custom attribute which sets the value of the `TextView` component and the `EditText` simply handles user input (limited to digits) and has a backing property converting the text entered to a `Float`.

In the `SwitchableTextField` (which extends a `ConstraintLayout`), I have more custom attributes being the following:

- defaultCurrency: String <= Used to set the content of the `TextView` in the `AmountEditText`
- conversionCurrency: String <= Used alongside the converted value from the `EditText` in the `AmountEditText` to display in the `Chip`
- conversionDirection: Boolean <= Used to define which way the conversion is going

The code I am having issues with is in the `SwitchableTextField` and is the following (Some parts have been removed for simplicity's sake):

```
class SwitchableTextField(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    var defaultCurrency: String = CURRENCY_EUR
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                field = value
                binding.mainAmountField.currency = value
            }
        }

    var mainAmount: Float = 0f
        get() = binding.mainAmountField.tokenAmount.toString().parseDecimalNumber()
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                field = value
                convertAmount(value)
            }
        }

    var conversionCurrency: String = CURRENCY_SYMBOL
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                field = value
            }
        }

    var convertedAmount: Float = 0f

    var assetAmount: Float = 0f

    var conversionDirection: Boolean = true

    var listener: AmountInputListener? = null

    init {
        isSaveEnabled = true
        applyUserAttributes(context, attrs)
        binding.mainAmountField.currency = defaultCurrency
        binding.mainAmountField.addOnTextChangedListener { text ->
            mainAmount = text.parseDecimalNumber()
        }
        binding.currencySwitchButton.setOnClickListener {
            switchConversionDirection()
        }
    }

    private fun applyUserAttributes(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.SwitchableCurrencyField,
            0,
            0
        )

        defaultCurrency = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SwitchableCurrencyField_defaultCurrency)
            ?: defaultCurrency

        conversionCurrency =
            typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SwitchableCurrencyField_conversionCurrency)
                ?: conversionCurrency

        conversionDirection =
            typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.SwitchableCurrencyField_convertFromAsset, true)

        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    // Some internal code

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        return SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState()).apply {
            childrenStates = saveChildViewStates()
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchSaveInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>?) {
        dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container)
    }

    internal class SavedState : AbsSavedState {
        internal var childrenStates: SparseArray<Parcelable>? = null

        constructor(superState: Parcelable?) : super(superState)

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        constructor(source: Parcel) : super(source) {
            childrenStates = source.readSparseArray(javaClass.classLoader)
        }

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
            out.writeSparseArray(childrenStates as SparseArray<Any>)
        }

        companion object {
            @Suppress("UNUSED")
            @JvmField
            val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> {
                override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel) = SavedState(source)
                override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<SavedState?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }

    public override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        when (state) {
            is SavedState -> {
                super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
                state.childrenStates?.let { restoreChildViewStates(it) }
            }
            else -> super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchRestoreInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>?) {
        dispatchThawSelfOnly(container)
    }
}
```

Assume I have the following attributes set for the view:

- defaultCurrency = "EUR"
- conversionCurrency = "USD"
- conversionDirection = true

Upon entering "10" in the `EditText`, the view displays the following:

```
 10 EUR
// Button
11.87 USD
```

Pressing the ImageButton works as intended and both the values and currency abbreviations switch. However, the issue I have is that when I navigate to the next fragment after having switched (meaning USD is in the `AmountEditText` and not EUR anymore), returning to the fragment with this view keeps the amount in the `EditText` but returns the defined attributes to the values they had originally: defaultCurrency = "EUR", conversionCurrency = "USD", conversionDirection = true

The workflow I expect to happen is the following:

```
 10 EUR                             11.87 USD                                11.87 USD
// Button -- Switching currency --> // Button -- Next fragment then back --> // Button
11.87 USD                            10 EUR                                   10 EUR
```

What actually happens is:

```
 10 EUR                             11.87 USD                                11.87 EUR
// Button -- Switching currency --> // Button -- Next fragment then back --> // Button
11.87 USD                            10 EUR                                  14.09 USD
```

Meaning the text entered in the `EditText` stays (which is good) but the rest is reset and hence the conversion is incorrect.

I suspect the issue comes from the custom attributes being read from the `TypedArray` and resetting the data restored but I have no idea how I should correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather simple but took me long enough to find.

Removing the `if (field != value)` from the properties and correctly implementing the `SavedState` with `internal var ...` for each of the properties that require saving does the trick.

**NOTE :** The `readBoolean` and `writeBoolean` functions for a `Parcel` exist only from API 29 so using another type was required (in my case a custom enum for the attributes resulting in an int).

Here is the resulting `onSaveInstanceState` function from which you can deduce the remaining code in the other functions:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
    return SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState()).apply {
        childrenStates = saveChildViewStates()
        defaultCurrency = this@SwitchableCurrencyField.defaultCurrency
        conversionCurrency = this@SwitchableCurrencyField.conversionCurrency
        conversionDirection = this@SwitchableCurrencyField.conversionDirection
        mainAmount = this@SwitchableCurrencyField.mainAmount
    }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to save internal EditText focus state too?

Comment: I didn't try/need to but I'd assume it's also possible